# d3.jzoom from same scale lavel not working properly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, svg, d3.js

I am using d3.zoom for my map. For some reason that I don't understand at some specific scale level zoom function is not working properly. And just on the right side of the map??? Thre is some kind of translation to the right and I can not pan any more my map.

This is js of my svg map.

> ```
> import * as d3 from "d3"; export default {
> name: "KartaHrvatske",
> props: ["name"],
> mounted(){
>     var svg = d3.select("#map") 
>     const zoom = d3.zoom()
>                    .translateExtent([[0,0],[10000000,8200000]])
>                    .scaleExtent([1, 10])
>                    .on("zoom", zoomed)
>                    
>     svg.call(zoom) 
>
>     function zoomed({transform}){
>         svg.select("#wrap").attr("transform", transform)
>     }
> } }
> ```

I am puting gif capture of my map, the left side zooming which is working ok
[image]

And the right side of the map which have some kind of translation
[image]

Does anyone have idea why this is happening and what can I do? I am using vue framework.

Comment: How did you derive your zoom translate extent? And I'm assuming  you are using d3-tile given the values?

Comment: My viewBox of svg map is viewBox="500000 600000 9300000 7889983" . So I was playing with widthe and height to be a litter biger because there is hidden part of map. Numbers are biger because data are created in CorelDraw and I needed to use higer drawing precision (1:10000 units) for exporting .cdr to .svg. for map to be with smooth lines. Interesting part is that for lower drawing precision (1:1 units) for exporting d3.zoom is working perfectly fine. No, I didin't use d3-tile.

Comment: Remove `translateExtent`. Do you still have the problem?

Comment: I already tryed that, even if I remove trenaslateExtent, as well as scaleExtent. the same is happening.

Comment: For now I did't find solution to this problem. Temporary solution is that I tracked scaleExtent to which the map works well, so insted scaleExtent([1, 10]) now is scaleExtent([1, 4.7]). But the question is still actual if anyone hvae idea.